# Which among the following cannot be the image of interval $[0,1)$ under a continuous map

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continous map then which of the following cannot be the image of

$[0,1)$ under $f$ ?

(a) $0$

(b) $(0,1)$

(c) $[0,1)$

(d) $[0,1]$

Now , I know the following theorem if $f$ is a continuous map iff inverse image of every closed set is a closed set.

So, (a) and (d) must be the correct  choices, 
But for option (a) I can easily set $f(x) = 0$, hence it must be incorrect.

But I don't really understand why isn't option (a) the correct choice, According to the theorem all the hypothesis are satisfied hence $0$ should be one of the answer.

Can someone please clear my doubt as why is option (a) Not the correct choice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only good way to go about this really is to apply the property that $f$ maps compacts to compacts. So we see that $f([0,1])$ is compact, and $f([0,1])=f([0,1))\cup f(\{1\})$, but the latter is a single point, and adding a single point to $(0,1)$ can never make it closed (hence, not compact). Hence, $(0,1)$ must be wrong.

As for the other options:

$\{0\}=f([0,1))$ if $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

$[0,1)=f([0,1))$ if $f(x)=x$

$[0,1]=f([0,1))$ if $f(x)=2\cdot|\frac{1}{2}-x|$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Can you tell me where id the flaw in my reasoning ? As you have written in the answer both (a) and (d) are the possible images,but according to the theorem I have quoted this shouldn't be possible.                                                                                Can you please tell me where is my mistake in applying the theorem ?

Comment: Well, your mistake is that $A\subseteq f (f^{-1}(A)),$ but equality need not hold unless $f$ is injective. You can even see this in the last example, where $f^{-1}([0,1])=[0,2]$ which is closed, as your theorem states. This also somehow illustrates that it's important that continuity is defined using *pre*-images rather than images.

Comment: Thank you for answering my doubt!

Answer (score 1):

If this were a test question, and "$0$" were not a typo for "$\{0\}$", I would consider it an extremely unfair question, because there are two contradictory answers to the question, both of which seem to me to be reasonable.  The problem is that the image of any subset of $\ \mathbb{R}\ $ must be a *subset* of $\ \mathbb{R}\ $, whereas $0$ is an *element* of $\ \mathbb{R}\ $.

As [WoolierThanThou's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3451629/which-among-the-following-cannot-be-the-image-of-interval-0-1-under-a-contin/3451667#3451667) has done, one can reasonably interpret the question as actually asking whether $\ \{0\}\ $ can be the image of $\ [0,1)\ $ under a continuous mapping, to which the answer is "yes", as WoolierThanThou shows.

However, in some contexts (in the set-theoretical foundations of Mathematics, for instance), $0$ is *defined* to be the *empty set*.  Thus, a bright and well-informed student could very reasonably take the question to be asking whether the *number* $0$ itself—considered either as the empty set, or as just a number rather than a set of numbers—can be the image of $\ [0,1)\ $ under a continuous mapping, to which the correct answer is "no", because the image of a non-empty set must be a *non-empty set* of numbers.